# Insert days of a month into a database using prepared statements PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to build an application where users can insert data per day of a month.
For that to happen I need to let the user create all days of a certain month (e.g.: current month).

With the click of a button I want it to get the current month and then use that data to get all days and make SQL Inserts for each month.

For example:

```
$monthname=date('F');
$monthnumber=date('m');
$getyear=date('Y');

    Loop this until it has inserted all days of $monthnumber:
INSERT INTO $monthdatadays (id, dayname, daynumber, monthname, $monthnumber, year, data1, data2) VALUES ('', '$dayname', 'day1', '$monthname', '$monthnumber', '$getyear', '$somedata', '$somedata2')
INSERT INTO $monthdatadays (id, dayname, daynumber, monthname, $monthnumber, year, data1, data2) VALUES ('', '$dayname', 'day2', '$monthname', '$monthnumber', '$getyear', '$somedata', '$somedata2')
INSERT INTO $monthdatadays (id, dayname, daynumber, monthname, $monthnumber, year, data1, data2) VALUES ('', '$dayname', 'day3', '$monthname', '$monthnumber', '$getyear', '$somedata', '$somedata2')
Until the end of the month, but then months do have different amount of days.
```

How can I achieve this using prepared statements like this one:

```
if($exampleps= $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO $pstable(id, name, summary, full, closedopen, createdby, createdat, editedby, editedat, date, time)VALUES('', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"))
{
$exampleps -> bind_param("ssssssssss", $name, $summary, $full, $status, $createdby, $createdat, $editedby, $editedat, $date, $time);
$exampleps -> execute();
$exampleps -> close();
}
```

Comment: so what seems to be the problem? error messages?

Comment: Its just that I dont know how to do such a thing, I know the while loop but that doesnt work in this situation.

Comment: so in this month (which is september), you want to loop all days? from 1-30?

Comment: Yes and then insert each day into the database, with additional data as shown in the first code part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop each day. You could use `DatePeriod`. Example:

```
// setup dates
$begin = new DateTime();
$end = new DateTime();
$begin->modify('first day of this month');
$end->modify('last day of this month');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D'); // 1 day interval
$range = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'db');
$sql = "INSERT INTO $monthdatadays (id, dayname, daynumber, monthname, $monthnumber, year, data1, data2) VALUES ('', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

foreach($range as $k => $date) {

    $somedata = 'whatever';
    $somedata2 = 'whatever';
    $dayname = $date->format('l');
    $day = 'day' . $date->format('j');
    $monthname = $date->format('F');
    $monthnumber = $date->format('n');
    $year = $date->format('Y');

    $stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $dayname, $day, $monthname, $monthnumber, $year, $somedata, $somedata2);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for learning me this, ill go try it out in my code!

Comment: @user3615331 sure no prob!

Answer (score 0):

You Can use MySQL NOW() function Return the current date and time.

**E.g.**

```
mysqli_query("INSERT INTO users (first, last, date_time) VALUES ('$first', '$last', now())");
```

**You can apply**

```
  $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO $pstable(id, name, summary, full, closedopen, createdby, createdat, editedby, editedat, date, time) VALUES('', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, now(), ?, now(), CURDATE(),CURTIME())");
```